# Servlets: sending 2 requests to JSP

Tags: java, excel, jsp, servlets, arraylist

I have a form with drop-down box on JSP page. User chose what kind of documentation he would like to get. Post is send to servlet. Then servlet is getting data from different files combines them and add to arrayList. Send it back to JSP:

```
rules = vp.getProperyRules();//ArrayList<RuleObject>
        request.setAttribute("rules", rules);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("rulesDocumentation.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Then JSP is printing them out in nice table. But I was asked to give an user opportunity to download an excel file as well. When he clicks "Get Documentation" button I want to add a link that will allow him to get a report as well as printing out table with documentation.

So I have couple of questions:

1. Now I am sending back Arraylist of all rules contained in documentation. Should I modify it to send excel file as well?
2. Or I should just create link that will point to temp file on server(report) when user will click on that link he will download a file. How to do it? Modify response that it will send arraylist and fileName of temp report stored on server side?

I would really appreciate your help

Comment: The answer is in the question: "I want to add a link that will allow him to get a report". So all you need is the information necessary to generate that link. And the complete excel file is not necessary to generate a link. All you need is the path and name of the excel file.

Comment: Then how to modify current response? Add two values at the end of that array?

Comment: Which array are you talking about? Store a FileDescription object, containing what you need to generate the link, in a request attribute. If each rule is associated with a file to download, then add a FileDescription property to the RuleObject class, and generate a link for each rule.

Comment: In request attribute I store objects that are later printed out in table

Comment: And? A request can contain as many attributes you want. What is the problem?

Comment: OMG thanks a lot I didn't know that :)
So I can have something like that?
`request.setAttribute("rules", rules);`
`request.setAttribute("file", filePath);`

Comment: Of course you can. And in the JSP, you'll use `${rules}` to access the rules list, and `${file}` to access the file path.